# Having issues with my website not being responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having an issue with my website not being responsive even though I already created the code to make it so. The images on my site don't get rearranged when I change the size of the browser.

The website is [whoissaveliy.com](http://whoissaveliy.com)

Below is my responsive.css file which contains the code that I created to make my site responsive. As well as my index.html file code. Please let me know what else you may need to see or know in order to help me with the issue.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Saveliy Yusufov | Working Professional</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?  family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
```

**responsive.css**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/**********************************
TWO COLUMN LAYOUT
***********************************/

  #primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  #secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }
/**********************************
PAGE: PORTFOLIO
***********************************/

   #gallery li:nth-child(3+1) {
  clear: left;
  } 

  #gallery li {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 28.3333%;
  }
}
/**********************************
ABOUT
***********************************/

.profile-photo {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5% 80px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {
/**********************************
HEADER
***********************************/ 
  nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: right;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 45%;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  header {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #599868;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
}

    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/**********************************
TWO COLUMN LAYOUT
***********************************/

  #primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  #secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }
/**********************************
PAGE: PORTFOLIO
***********************************/

   #gallery li:nth-child(3+1) {
  clear: left;
  } 

  #gallery li {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 28.3333%;
  }
}
/**********************************
ABOUT
***********************************/

.profile-photo {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5% 80px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {
/**********************************
HEADER
***********************************/ 
  nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: right;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 45%;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  header {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #599868;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried viewing your website on your phone, or resizing your browser? When I viewed your website, your media queries worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this media query in responsive.css itself. Use firefox and press (shift+ctrl+M) then select 480*320 and see your new styles are applying in that resolution. And also you need to add media query at the end of web page css